# What is the difference between disabling hibernation and idling time for a NAS?

Tags: speed, nas

I have two D-LINK DNS-323 NAS boxes with two Seagate drives in each. The first one is about a year old, the second one about three months. The first two on Monster are each 1.5T drives while the last two on Origami are 2T drives. I have never been overly happy with the Monster drives but, outside of poor throughput on small files, they have been consistently available to all programs after I put a batch file into my startup to do a directly listing of each. I added the two new drives when I added the Origami box. But, watching the dos box that comes up, I rarely see both listed before the box disappears. Other programs, backups, Belarc, even my file browsers, seem to have a dickens of a time seeing O: and P:.

Finally, I decided to go into setup and turn off hibernation. Performance HAS been better since and Belarc, for instance, now sees both drives. At the time of poking around, I noticed an Idle Time feature too.

What is the difference between the two settings? And for added points, how much trouble am I in for turning off hibernation? The super bonus round ... anything ELSE I should have done?

Thanks in advance, GM

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the screen you're looking at I can't be completely certain as I don't own or have one of these nas' to look at.

The manual for this model lists idle time in a couple of places.  Where mentioned it is to do with how long your browser is connected into the NAS configuration screens and you're not doing anything.  When the idle time passes, it automatically logs you out.  But I don't think that is what you're looking at.

Hypernation is to do with shutting the drives down to save power.

The hybernation feature is not mentioned in the online manual at all.  So idle time is more likely be related to how long the drives are not accessed before shutting them down and entering the NAS into the hybernation state.

Turning off hybernation is probably a good thing for performance at the cost of a little extra power.  It's debatable as to whether either will increase or decrease the life of the drives.  Some say it's better to leave it spinning.  In my experience, no difference at all.
So if you don't mind the power being used, keep it off.    You might like to experiment wit the idle time.  Make it longer if you're concerned about power consumption.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the analysis. I've already noticed fewer hiccups with the Origami set of drives and feel comfortable with the power expenditure. As for the idling time, now that you've explained it to me, there seems no reason to touch the setting. I'm virtually never in the config section with my browser. Two times in three months for five-ten minutes total. Your effort is much appreciated. Thanks.